# Procedure de MySQL não reconhece o WHERE e apresenta erro

Tags: mysql

Ao executar a procudure abaixo o MySQL Workbench apresenta o erro:

> "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column. To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."

Entretanto, o único  `UPDATE` da procedure utiliza a chave primária da tabela.

```
    DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE PROCEDURE Editar_Produtos(
     IN Id_Pro INT,
     IN Cod_Int VARCHAR (21),
     IN Nom_Pro VARCHAR (55),
     IN Id_Cat INT,
     IN Id_Cla INT,
     IN Id_Sub INT,
     IN Id_Mil INT,
     IN Id_Med INT,
     IN Id_Mar INT,
     IN Vlr_Cust DECIMAL (9,2),
     IN Vlr_Vend DECIMAL (9,2),
     IN Id_Un INT,
     IN Id_Tpd INT
    )
    BEGIN
     UPDATE ktsproduto 
     SET COD_INT = Cod_Int, 
         NOM_PRO = Nom_Pro, 
         ID_CAT = Id_Cat, 
         ID_CLA = Id_Cla, 
         ID_SUB = Id_Sub, 
         ID_MIL = Id_Mil, 
         ID_MED = Id_Med, 
         ID_MAR = Id_Mar, 
         VLR_CUST = Vlr_Cust, 
         VLR_VEND = Vlr_Vend, 
         ID_UN = Id_Un,      
         ID_TPD = Id_Tpd 
     WHERE ID_PRO = Id_Pro;    
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;

    CALL Editar_Produtos(
    '417',"KTSKTSKTS","KENNEDY TEIXIERA",'1','1','1','1','1','1','250.99','500.99','1','1');
```

Não entendo o porquê do erro, uma vez que estou usando a clausula `WHERE` com a Chave Primária da tabela.

Se possível, não quero rodar `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;`, por questão de segurança.

Comment: Reinicia o servidor mysql e testa.

Comment: ID_PRO é uma chave ?

Comment: Sim, é uma chave.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, depois de fazer muitos testes, percebe que ao retirar o underline " _ "  de todas as variáveis funcionou perfeitamente, ou seja Id_Pro, Id_Cat ficaram assim IdPro, IdCat configurei desta fora e deu certinho. Agradeço as demais pessoas que se importaram com minha pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Não consegui compreender o motivo da pergunta ser fechada. Me parece uma boa questão e com o problema bem exposto.

Comment: @KennedyTeixeira, embora tenha "dado a volta ao problema", acho que consigo explicar a razão dele na minha resposta. Chegou a verificar se funciona adequadamente?

Comment: @tvdias muito obrigado, a sua proposta de solução funcionou, agora posso organizar melhor meu código, este tópico é muito útil, não deveria ser fechado.

Comment: Quanto ao fechamento, vamos ver se é revisto. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O MySQL está considerando ambos `ID_PRO` e `Id_Pro` no teu where como `Id_Pro` que é passado como entrada da sua procedure. Neste caso, se fosse desativado o `Safe Update`, todos os registros seriam atualizados, caso encontrada alguma coluna com nome válido. O mesmo pode acontecer quando a sua procedure for utilizada fora do `MySQL Workbench`. Como há diferenças de "case sensitive" entre Windows e Linux, esse comportamento pode variar dependendo do seu sistema operacional.

Uma forma de resolver este problema é identificando as tabela junto das colunas:

```sql
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE Editar_Produtos(
 IN Id_Pro INT,
 IN Cod_Int VARCHAR (21),
 IN Nom_Pro VARCHAR (55),
 IN Id_Cat INT,
 IN Id_Cla INT,
 IN Id_Sub INT,
 IN Id_Mil INT,
 IN Id_Med INT,
 IN Id_Mar INT,
 IN Vlr_Cust DECIMAL (9,2),
 IN Vlr_Vend DECIMAL (9,2),
 IN Id_Un INT,
 IN Id_Tpd INT
)
BEGIN
 UPDATE ktsproduto 
 SET ktsproduto.COD_INT = Cod_Int, 
     ktsproduto.NOM_PRO = Nom_Pro, 
     ktsproduto.ID_CAT = Id_Cat, 
     ktsproduto.ID_CLA = Id_Cla, 
     ktsproduto.ID_SUB = Id_Sub, 
     ktsproduto.ID_MIL = Id_Mil, 
     ktsproduto.ID_MED = Id_Med, 
     ktsproduto.ID_MAR = Id_Mar, 
     ktsproduto.VLR_CUST = Vlr_Cust, 
     ktsproduto.VLR_VEND = Vlr_Vend, 
     ktsproduto.ID_UN = Id_Un,      
     ktsproduto.ID_TPD = Id_Tpd 
 WHERE ktsproduto.ID_PRO = Id_Pro;    
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL Editar_Produtos(
'417',"KTSKTSKTS","KENNEDY TEIXIERA",'1','1','1','1','1','1','250.99','500.99','1','1');
```

Comment: Se importaria de ao menos comentar o motivo do voto negativo?

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, achei a pergunta numa fila de análises, mas talvez a resposta tenha sido negativada porque ela apenas corrigiu o código e abordou superficialmente o problema do AP que é a falta de compreensão sobre a sensibilidade a diferenciação entre maiúsculas e minúsculas no SQL. Claro posso estar equivocado, as pessoas negativam pelos mais absurdos motivos, mas de uma perspectiva lógica acredito ser esse o motivo mais plausível.

Comment: Quase posso dar como certo que esse seja o motivo, lendo na pergunta o último comentário do autor é visível que ele chegou a uma solução por meio de conclusão equivocada e ele necessita de esclarecimentos e ainda não sabe.

Comment: Também não consegui compreender o motivo da pergunta ser fechada. Me parece uma boa questão e com o problema bem exposto.

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada por se tratar de sucessivos erros de sintaxe. Em momento algum disse que era uma boa pergunta.